# moto G having problems

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I bought Moto G(2nd gen)and received it yesterday from flipkart and problems started with it since day one. sometimes when I receive a call, I am not able to hear the voice on the other side, and I even do not hear any voice when I dial a number. I have to restart my phone to set it right.  In addition to it, I am not even able to call someone. Whenever I tried to call, ''call ended'' shows up.

Comment: Have you tried calling to multiple numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been noticed that moto g had this problem where voice is not clear, or similar issues.

So, In case you are using two sim slots try removing the other one , and then restart it because sometimes it conflicts when using two SIM card. If the problem still stays them go for replacement of device.

Comment: Till now I have inserted only one sim. I have tried it both slots one by one. Restarted it multiple times. The network signal strength is full. But "call ended" shows up whenever i try to call.

Comment: I think then you must replace it.